# Check instance of a method is already executed or not

Tags: c#, azure

I have a big problem that is I have implemented a scheduler in my windows azure application that can execute a particular task in each day at 17.29. For the implementation I am using a third party tool that is Quartz. And I use following code to enable my scheduler

```
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("mySendMailJob", typeof(SendMailJob));
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(17, 29); 
trigger.Name = "mySendMailTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

And I place this code in my application start.

My question is if I execute this code once then my scheduler start it working. Next time need not invoke. So how can I check if the scheduler is already invoked or not? If I place this code in application start each time execute the same code, that is totally useless. If there is any method. If anyone know please help me. I am using C#

Comment: If you are using AdoJobStore, then each time the trigger fired, this information will be stored on DB, you can access DB to detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on the question "how to execute something only once". I recommend to most folks to use a self electing controller pattern. I explain that [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119614/execute-methode-in-windows-azure-with-multiple-instances/11123160#11123160).